# How can I add a Picture to a QWidget in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

How can I add or import a picture to a `QWidget`? I have found a clue.
I can add a `Label` and add a `Picture` in that label. I need the arguments 
for the `QPicture()`. The probable I can use is, `QLabel.setPicture(self.QPicture)`.

Answer (score 19):

Here is some code that does what you and @erelender described:

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
window.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 200)

pic = QtGui.QLabel(window)
pic.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 100)
#use full ABSOLUTE path to the image, not relative
pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd() + "/logo.png"))

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A generic `QWidget` does not have `setPixmap()`.  If this approach does not work for you, you can look at making your own custom widget that derives from `QWidget` and override the `paintEvent` method to display the image.

Comment: this puts the QLabel ontop of all the widgets I have , how would you put it behind every widget and always fit to width of window if resized?

Answer (score 15):

`QPicture` is not what you want. `QPicture` records and replays `QPainter` commands. What you want is `QPixmap`. Give a filename to the `QPixmap` constructor, and set this pixmap to the label using `QLabel.setPixmap()`.

An implementation example in python would be:

```
label = QLabel() 
pixmap = QPixmap('path_to_your_image')
label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet in your GUI script:

```
image = QtGui.QLabel(self)
image.setGeometry(50, 40, 250, 250)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\\address\\to\\your_image.png")
image.setPixmap(pixmap)
image.show()
```