# How to load and show a rescaled image with pyqt4

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286864/how-can-i-add-a-picture-to-a-qwidget-in-pyqt4), but without description how to rescale the image. I only found the [C++ specs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#scaled) for `QPixmap` so far, and a [reference guide](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/index.html) for `pyQT4`. But the latter does not seem to have any reference to QPixmap.

Question: Does anyone know how to show a rescaled version of the full image based on the code in the first link, and/or where I can find the `pyQt4` specs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [QPixmap.scaledToHeight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#scaledToHeight) or [QPixmap.scaledToWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#scaledToWidth) method:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
window.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 200)
pic = QtGui.QLabel(window)
pic.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 200)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(FILENAME)
pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(200)
pic.setPixmap(pixmap)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can find [documentation on PyQT classes (including QPixmap) here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/classes.html).

Sometimes when I am lazy and do not want to read documentation, I use this:

```
def describe(obj):
    for key in dir(obj):
        try:
            val = getattr(obj, key)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        if callable(val):
            help(val)
        else:
            print('{k} => {v}'.format(k = key, v = val))
        print('-'*80)

pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(FILENAME)
describe(pixmap)
```

which prints lots of output about all the attributes of the object passed to `describe`. In this case, you can find relevant methods by searching for the string `-> QPixmap` since these are the methods that return a new `QPixmap`. That's how I found `scaledToHeight` and `scaledToWidth`.

Comment: @JGreenwell: Thank you for the link. Since this Q is tagged `pyqt4` I've linked to the Qt4.8 version of the docs.